# C++ code formatter with API support to know if line belongs to a particular function

Tags: c++, formatting, ide

We are planning to build a tool which takes compilable C++ source file and a number as input and outputs name of the function for which the line number belongs to.

IDEs have folding\unfolding support of functions. Meaning, they are able to parse the file and know the starting line number and ending line numbers of all functions within the file. But I think IDEs dont expose any APIs to use those functionalities outside.

Is there any tool/framework available which is exposing APIs to achieve this functionality.

Thanks...

Comment: You would be wise to build your tool on top of llvm

Comment: Thanks @Taekahn .. 
By the way I have only built SO files, source files and llvm-tools. I dont want to build again. So I am thinking of approach 1. Find start and end addresses of function using llvm-disassemble-symbols=<symbol_name> <SoName> 2. convert start and end addresses to line numbers. This way we will get to know start and end of function in file.  3. now we know if given line number is in range or not.

Comment: any other suggestions please?